# Python dictionary colon to equal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sample dict obj I need to convert `:` to `=`. For example:

```
temp = {"name" : "user1", "age" : "20"}
```

to:

```
{"name" = "user1", "age" = "20"}
```

This will be the params to a function. The keys and values are dynamically generated which are not known at the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

Solution
Function name (**temp) works.